# KPI Showing the total % instead of the last % - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, kpi

I have a set of KPI cards I am creating that I want to show the total percentage instead of the last %.  I have tried using the stand alone Microsoft KPI card and I have also tried the KPI Indicator visual that is available for download.  The KPI Indicator allows Sum, Average, and Value.  Unfortuantley the Average seems to be taking the average of all the %s in the dataset and not the values of the dax formula in totality.

The KPI sparkline graph looks great and exaclty correct, its just the KPI value that is wrong.
Example data with what it is doing now vs what I want it to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your measure definition?

Comment: It’s as simple as FinanceData[Expense] / FinaceData[Base] with a Date table date column used for the time series.